# How to restart Azure Web App with schedule

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

I would like to restart my Azure Web App on 06:00 everyday.

I find a reference from [Azure App Services: Automate Application restart using Web Job](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/karansingh/2017/02/10/azure-app-services-automate-application-restart-using-web-job/)

But, there's some error in this post.

- Save-AzureProfile => Save-AzureRmContext
- Select-AzureRmProfile => Import-AzureRmContext

After fix this, run at local ,it's perfect.

When i create a web job on my Azure Web App, that get a error

[image: InvalidOperation]

Looks like it's not support Stop-AzureRmWebApp

Is there a soluction？

Comment: Try to isolate issue via Kudu PowerShell console to get WebJobs out of the equation. https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Isolating-WebJobs-and-Deployment-script-issues

Comment: Here is an answer on how to restart your web-app using logic-apps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59633629/44815

Answer (score 0):

I tested it on my side. The PowerShell code which provided by the blob is working fine on my side. Here are the detail steps I did.

Step 1. Create a folder named TestRestartWebApp.
Step 2. Generate the profile file to that folder.

```
Save-AzureRmProfile -Path "D:\TestRestartWebApp\azureprofile.json"
```

Step 3. Create a PS file named run.ps1 in that folder.

[image]

Step 4. Following are the code which I put in run.ps1.

```
$ProgressPreference= "SilentlyContinue"
Select-AzureRmProfile -Path "azureprofile.json"
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId 'my subscription id'
Stop-AzureRmWebApp -Name 'my web app name' -ResourceGroupName 'my resource group name'
```

Step 5. Compress this folder and create a WebJob using the compressed file.

After upper steps, I can see the logs in WebJob dashboard. The Web App has been stopped.

[image]

Please double check your steps, are there any differences between yours and mine. Have you set the right path for profile file in run.ps1 file.